# copying the structure in the linked list

Tags: c

Here I am copying the structure from one node to another but when I encounter the last node I will have a segmentation fault since `temp_clsf->next` in `memcpy` will be pointing to a invalid location, how can I fix this? I cant free `temp_clsf` as it is not dynamic allocation.

```
while(temp_clsf!=NULL)
{
    memcpy(&temp_clsf, &temp_clsf->next, sizeof(struct classifier));
    if(temp_clsf->next ==NULL)
        return;
    else
        temp_clsf = temp_clsf->next;
}
```

Comment: @cnicutar: i have given a detailed explanation here and i am stuck in this not able to proceed

Comment: I don't get this at all.  It seems crazy to copy your entire list every time your remove an item.  I don't understand why you don't just point change the start of your list point to the current first node's next pointer...

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, keep a pointer to the previous node. When the loop ends, update that node with a pointer to NULL

```
/* pseudo-code */
while () {
    prev = curr;
    /* ... */
}
prev->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the copy after the `if` ...

```
 while(temp_clsf!=NULL)
    {
    if(temp_clsf->next ==NULL)
    return;
    //else
    memcpy(&temp_clsf, &temp_clsf->next, sizeof(struct classifier));
    temp_clsf = temp_clsf->next;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use following condition in while.

```
while(temp_clsf->next!=NULL)
```

Comment: if `temp_clsf` itself is NULL, that comparison will attempt to dereference a null pointer: better test for both: `while(temp_clsf!=NULL && temp_clsf->next!=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, `temp_clsf->next` could be `NULL` so move the `NULL` check before the `memcpy`

```
while(temp_clsf != NULL)
{
    if(temp_clsf->next == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    memcpy(&temp_clsf, &temp_clsf->next, sizeof(struct classifier));

    temp_clsf = temp_clsf->next;
}
```

**Update**: `temp_clsf` and `temp_clsf->next` look like pointers to me. So your `memcpy` is taking address of pointers and overwriting what is there. Is this your intention? Not sure what `sizeof(struct classifier)` is as we do not have the structure types in your example.

Comment: if i do this it will not copy the last structure,since temp_clsf->next will be pointing to null, but the data i have in that instant of temp_clsf should be copied to the previous structure

Comment: So the memcpy should really be copying the data and not the pointers, right? What is the structure of the type for temp_clsf/classifier?

Comment: structure1->structure2->structure3->structure4->structure5
here i want to do a memcpy i.e if  i remove structure1 i want the output like structure1->structure2->structure3->structure4->structure5
but in my code i have removed structure1 i want resulting structure like this structure2->structure3->structure4->structure5
but i for my code i get a o/p like this structure2->structure3->structure4->structure4->structure5 when it come to structure5 temp_clsf->next will be NULL and it will come out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a shift of items, potentially to remove one.  If this was an ordered array, there would be no need to use a `next` pointer.  I'm not sure what other static allocation you are using, but you can simply do the following to remove the single item `temp_clsf->next`:

```
temp_clsf->next=temp_clsf->next->next;
```