# copying one structure to another in a linked list

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copying the structure in the linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948273/copying-the-structure-in-the-linked-list)

Here the input structure is like this

```
structure1->structure2->structure3->structure4->structure5
```

In my code I am doing a memcpy to remove structure.

In my code I have removed `structure1` i want resulting structure like this

```
structure2->structure3->structure4->structure5
```

But for my code I get a o/p like this

```
structure2->structure3->structure4->structure4->structure5
```

When it come to `structure5` `temp_clsf->next` will be NULL and it will come out of the loop without copying `structure5` I cannot free the structure as I have not a dynamic alloacation.

Can anyone please help me out?

```
while(temp_clsf!=NULL)
{
    if(temp_clsf->next ==NULL)
        return;
    memcpy(&temp_clsf, &temp_clsf->next, sizeof(struct classifier));
    temp_clsf = temp_clsf->next;
}
```